# converting json array data to js tree in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am creating js tree in asp.net core where i build to classes like

```
public class ChildClass
    {
     [Key]
        public int chId { get; set; }
        public string chName { get; set; }

       
        public int parentId { get; set; }
        
    }


public class ParentClass
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


public class TreeViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string parent { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
```

now i am creating method to list of treeviewmodel in the controller like

```
public IActionResult GetTree()
        {
            List<TreeViewModel> list = new List<TreeViewModel>();
            foreach (ParentClass type in _db.parent)
            {
                list.Add(new TreeViewModel { Id = type.Id.ToString(), parent = "#", text = type.Name });
            }
            foreach (ChildClass schild in _db.child)
            {
                list.Add(new TreeViewModel
                {
                    Id = schild.parentId.ToString(),
                    parent = schild.parentId.ToString(),
                    text = schild.chName.ToString()
                });
            }


            return Json(list);
        }
```

[{"id":"1","parent":"#","text":"Root"},{"id":"1","parent":"1","text":"Menu"}]

we r getting array on calling funtion in url and in the index.cshml we are using javacript and ajax to build jstree but failing in converting arrayo object to treeview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Simple jsTree</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "https://localhost:44359/TreeView/GetTree",
                success: function (json) {
                //console.log(json);
               createJSTree(json);
               }
            })
        });

        function createJSTree(jsondata) {
            
            $('#SimpleJSTree').jstree({
                "core": {
                    "check_callback": true,
                    'data': jsondata
                    
                },
                "plugins": ["contextmenu"],
                "contextmenu": {
                    "items": function ($node) {
                        var tree = $("#SimpleJSTree").jstree(true);
                        return {
                            "Create": {
                                "separator_before": false,
                                "separator_after": true,
                                "label": "Create",
                                "action": false,
                                "submenu": {
                                    "File": {
                                        "seperator_before": false,
                                        "seperator_after": false,
                                        "label": "File",
                                        action: function (obj) {
                                            $node = tree.create_node($node, { text: 'New 
                               File', type: 'file', icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-file' });
                                            tree.deselect_all();
                                            tree.select_node($node);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "Folder": {
                                        "seperator_before": false,
                                        "seperator_after": false,
                                        "label": "Folder",
                                        action: function (obj) {
                                            $node = tree.create_node($node, { text: 'New 
                                     Folder', type: 'default' });
                                            tree.deselect_all();
                                            tree.select_node($node);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "Rename": {
                                "separator_before": false,
                                "separator_after": false,
                                "label": "Rename",
                                "action": function (obj) {
                                    tree.edit($node);                                    
                                }
                            },
                            "Remove": {
                                "separator_before": false,
                                "separator_after": false,
                                "label": "Remove",
                                "action": function (obj) {
                                    tree.delete_node($node);
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="SimpleJSTree"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of using plugins to build treeview you can simply create your own logic for this. See [link](https://www.yogihosting.com/jquery-treeview/).

Comment: but i got task like that only i have to create the node then again i have add child node to them